# why token based approach more preferred these days?

Tags: java, session, cookies, session-cookies, access-token

In case of Cookie-based appproach, server stores cookies either in servers memory or in some db.

Even in case of token-based approach, still server has to store tokens in servers memory or in db.

So, whats the big deal if we use either cookie or token based? I mean we can go with traditional cookie based approach, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cookie based Authentication vs Token Authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication)

Comment: @NeerajJain My query is quite different. I am actually not asking difference between them.

Comment: @John but understanding the difference between them may help you to know why one is preferred over the other. And, more pertinently, it can help you to understand which one is preferred for your specific set of requirements, which we don't know. Maybe tokens are better for you, maybe not.

Comment: @AndyTurner can you able to answer my query?

Comment: does anyone can answer?